# Programmatically running audio with javascript in UIWebView with swift

Tags: javascript, swift, html, uiwebview, avaudioplayer

I have a project where I am using a UIWebView that loads local html, css and javascript. Everything works but when I try to play an audio `.ogg` file programmatically using javascript it will not work.

```js
var wing_sound = new Audio('audio/sfx_wing.ogg');
wing_sound.play()
```

This works fine in my browser. But in my UIWebView it refuses work. All other javascript works great, but when I try to make the audio play it just doesn't play!

#### So far I have tried this

```swift
self.webView = UIWebView() // we make a web view
self.webView?.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
self.webView?.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
self.webView?.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = false
self.webView?.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
self.view = self.webView // we insert the web view
```

#### As well as this

```swift
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    print(error)
}
```

And neither works. Does anyone have any suggestions??